# Check signup checkbox is check or not on checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout

Hello currently i am using one page checkout and i want to know that signup check-box is check or not on checkout page. How can i know that sign up is checked or not?

Comment: Please clarify the method in which you would like to "know" - javascript? php? frontend? backend? on order place? on registration?

Comment: in PHP. i want to in quote object,,

Comment: By signup checkbox do you mean newsletter subscription opt-in? Also at what step of checkout do you want to check it?

Comment: in order review step i want to checkout is sign up check or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod()
```

This value can be:

- empty - if the customer is already logged in
- `register` - if the customer chose to register
- `quest` - if the customer selected 'Checkout as guest'

**[EDIT]**
To know if a customer is logged in check this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();//true if the customer is logged in
```

Comment: i am getting NULL from getCheckoutMethod() when i choose signup option and i enter password

Comment: @KeyurShah where did you put your code?

Comment: on couponPostAction i want know that here customer is registered or login

Comment: the couponPostAction is not in the checkout process. Is in the cart. You don't know there if the customer is going to checkout as guest or register. You can only check if the customer is logged in.

Comment: thats'right ,,here i only know that customer is lo-gin or not if lo-gin then it display is_loggined,,is there any way i know that ?

Comment: I've added that to my answer